# CakePHP validation rule for uploaded image

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In the user form I have a field for a picture:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Document.submittedfile', array('label' => __('Billede')));  ?>
```

I had a validation made in controller, but it was not the best solution, so I have moved it to the Model, and since then it stop working. Here is the validation snippet from the model:

```
    'submittedfile'=>array(
        'rule' => 'savePicture',
        'message' => 'The image has to been in jpg, png, gif or pdf format and should not exceed 2MB')

public function savePicture($data){

    if(!empty($data['Document']['submittedfile'])){

    $file = $data['Document']['submittedfile'];

    $folder_url = WWW_ROOT.'img/uploads/users/';    

    if(file_exists($folder_url . $file['name'])){
    $now = date('Y-m-d-His');
    $file['name'] = $now.$file['name'];
    }

    if($file['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $file['type'] == 'image/png' || $file['type'] == 'image/gif' || $file['type'] == 'application/pdf' ){

     if($file['size'] <= 2097152){
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.'img/uploads/users/' . $file['name']);
        $this->request->data['User']['image'] = $file['name'];  

        return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }else{
        return false;
    }   

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

What happens now is that the validation rule is not being applied at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Variable $data in savePicture($data) {} will be something similar to below array. Change your code accordingly.

```
  [submittedfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => sample_file
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phptU4UKh
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 132499
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things not really well done in your code besides your issue.

- You're not using [is_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/is_uploaded_file) which opens a possible security issue.
- Storing all the files in the same folder can result in performance issues for the file system when you've got a large number of files in one folder.
- You're not using aliases but hard coded model names: $this->request->data['User'] should be $this->request->data[$this->alias] - assuming you're in the user model.
- You're not following the CakePHP coding conventions, not a must but I prefer to use the conventions from whatever framework I use

About the problem you've asked: Unit test your code if you want to use it or use the [UploadValidator](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/blob/master/Model/Behavior/UploadValidatorBehavior.php) behaviour from my [FileStorage plugin](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) which is fully unit tested. I'm not sure where your code fails, I would break it up into more methods (duplicate check, extension check) and unit test it, you usually find out what is wrong then.

Are you using savePicture() as validation method within your validation rules or are you calling it directly?

https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/blob/master/Model/Behavior/UploadValidatorBehavior.php